# Issues with writing and reading to/from a stream

Tags: database, sockets, io, bufferedreader

I know I posted a problem yesterday, that might look a look like the one I'm about to present to you. It's however most likely not the same, due to lessons learned from previous question.

*THE PROBLEM*: a readLine() statement just sits and waits for input. Please read:

I have a server that communicates with a client. The database used is postgresql.
The following thread is used to communicate with the client :

*(The part where it goes wrong is probably in the for loop)*

**Server:**

```
public class mobileComm implements Runnable {

private Socket sock;
private Connection connection;
private BufferedReader br;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        String name = br.readLine();
        String password = br.readLine();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));

        if (methods.checkContinue(name, password)) {
            methods.log(name + password);
            connection = methods.connectToDatabase();

            if (connection != null) {
                String getQuery =
                        "SELECT name, password, updatetext FROM accounts "
                        + "WHERE name = ? AND password= ?";
                String setQuery =
                        "UPDATE accounts SET doupdate = 'yes' "
                        + "WHERE name = ?'";
                PreparedStatement getPS = connection.prepareStatement(getQuery);
                PreparedStatement setPS = connection.prepareStatement(setQuery);
                getPS.setString(1, name);
                getPS.setString(2, password);
                ResultSet rs = getPS.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next() && rs.isLast()) {

                    boolean success = false;

                    bw.write("accept\n");
                    bw.flush();
                    setPS.setString(1, name);
                    setPS.executeUpdate();

                    String currentText = rs.getString("updatetext");
                    String updatedText;

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if (!(updatedText = getPS.executeQuery().getString("updatetext")).equals(currentText)) {
                            bw.write("update\n");
                            bw.flush();
                            bw.write(updatedText + "\n");
                            bw.flush();
                            success = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }

                    if (!success) {
                        bw.write("noupdate\n");
                        bw.flush();
                    }

                } else {
                    bw.write("decline\n");
                    bw.flush();
                }
                rs.close();
                getPS.close();
                setPS.close();
            }
        } else {
            bw.write("wrong\n");
            bw.flush();
        }

        bw.close();
        br.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        methods.log("Failed when creating brs and writers in mobileComm");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        methods.log("Error with sql in mobileComm thread");
    }
}

public mobileComm(Socket sock, BufferedReader br) {
    this.sock = sock;
    this.br = br;
}
}
```

**The code for the client that connects looks like this:**

```
        try {

        String line;
        Socket sock = new Socket("83.205.36.66", 80);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));

        writer.write("request\n");
        writer.write(jTextField1.getText() + "\n");
        writer.write(jTextField2.getText() + "\n");
        writer.flush();
        if ((line = reader.readLine()).equals("accept")) {
            System.out.print(line);
            jTextArea1.setText("Waiting for script to send data.");
            if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals("update")) {
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(reader.readLine()).useDelimiter("\\s*::\\s*");
                    ArrayList<String> items = null;
                    while (s.hasNext()) {
                        items.add(s.next());
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        jTextArea1.setText("");
                        jTextArea1.append(items.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                } else if (line == "noupdate") {
                    jTextArea1.setText("No script running.");
                }
            } else {
                jTextArea1.setText("Line is null");
            }

        } else if (line.equals("decline")) {
            jTextArea1.setText("Incorrect user/pass combination");
        } else if (line.equals("wrong")) {
            jTextArea1.setText("Certain characters/strings were not allowed");
        }
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        jTextArea1.append("Server not available. Please try again later.");
    }
```

The actual *problem* occurs at the

```
            if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Boolean check. The GUI of the client app just freezes, like it's waiting for input.

The for loop in the server thread is because it waits for new database input from another thread

I deleted the entire for loop and just wrote

```
bw.write("update\n);
bw.flush();
bw.bw.write("this::is::a::test\n);
bw.flush();
```

Instead. The readLine() still makes the app freeze like it's waiting for input..

***So why won't the readLine() "execute"?***

Also, the jTextArea1 text doesn't change to "Waiting for script to send data." as it should.

Just ask if you're wondering about anything.

Notes:
no exception is thrown in the client app.
the client app prints out accept, showing that it reads the a line the first time I ask it to.

Any help appreciated. Really, any help.

Mike.

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone will answer your question, because you have made no effort to provide a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)

Comment: I realize that this is makes people go tl;dr, but I honestly don't see any other way of formulating it. :/

Comment: Updated the question now. Hopefully it's more straight forward

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

never called next() in the for loop when reading from the database, thus never actually reading anything from the database.